# The Submit on HTML form is not submitting the data to the relevant page

Tags: html, forms, submit, href

I'm trying to add a template contact form to a site but unable to get the custom html form to submit. On submit, the 'Contact form submitted' message appears but no email is received. The page the data is passed to works if run independently, but not from the form, any ideas?

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<div class="success_wrapper">
    <div class="success-message">Contact form submitted</div>
    </div>
        <label class="name">
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name:" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="email">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="E-mail:" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="phone">
            <input type="text" name="Contact" id="Contact" placeholder="Phone:" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"/>
        <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="message">
            <textarea name="Message" id="Message" placeholder="Message:" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
        <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
        </label>
    <div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btns">
        <a href="#" data-type="reset" class="btn">Clear</a>
        <a href="#" data-type="submit" class="btn">Submit</a>                                   
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Not see  used for submitting form data and suspect this may be the issue? The 'Clear' button works as expected.

I've set up a simple form like this one below, and it does exactly what i'd expect, but the company want the form to match the rest of site hence trying to do it this way.:

```
<form  action="contactengine.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your name:<br>
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your email:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your message:<br>
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
</form>
```

Here is the code that sends the mail:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$EmailTo = "grahamdrummond@sky.com";
$Subject = "Test Contact Form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Contact'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

$Body  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$Body .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$Body .= 'From: '. $EmailFrom . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

$from = "$Email <>";
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 

// send email 
mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: I've ruled out the 'sending of the email' part, that has been tested by manually entering the form data in the php and running the page from browser - the issue is with the form itself.

Comment: Where is the code to send a mail ??

Comment: You need to include an example of all of your code in the question. Is there a missing javascript file which submits the form?

Comment: @jonhendrix added now

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's nothing in the html which is going to submit the form. Check this codepen for one way to do it: https://codepen.io/jonolayton/pen/mGMJeX

```js
function submitted() {
  
  alert("The form has been submitted!");
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" action="contactengine.php">
<div class="success_wrapper">
    <div class="success-message">Contact form submitted</div>
    </div>
        <label class="name">
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Name:" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="email">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="E-mail:" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="phone">
            <input type="text" name="Contact" id="Contact" placeholder="Phone:" data-constraints="@Required @JustNumbers"/>
        <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
        </label>
        <label class="message">
            <textarea name="Message" id="Message" placeholder="Message:" data-constraints='@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)'></textarea>
        <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
        <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
        </label>
    <div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="btns">
        <a href="#" data-type="reset" class="btn">Clear</a>
        <a href="#" data-type="submit" class="btn">Submit</a>                      
    </div>
    </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitted()">
</form>
```

At present, you're (I think) trying to use the data attribute in the link:

```
<a href="#" data-type="submit" class="btn">Submit</a>
```

to submit the form. But the data attribute will not submit a form on it's own, without some code (usually javascript) to do something with it. You can read more about data attributes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

You need to add some html, or some javascript (or both) which will actually submit the form on being clicked.